# Error CS1525 C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need some help pls

Error CS1525 C# Invalid expression term <= at the the 51 code

http://in2gpu.com/2014/08/25/build-minecraft-unity-part4-worldgen/ 
Creating worldGenerator

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class WorldGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Public fields are visible and their values can be changed dirrectly in the editor

    // Drag and drop here the Voxel from the Scene
    // Used to create new instances
    public GameObject Voxel;

    //Specify the dimensions of the world
    public float SizeX;
    public float SizeZ;
    public float SizeY;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        // Start the world generation coroutine
        // StartCoroutine function always returns immediately, however you can yield the result. 
        StartCoroutine(SimpleGenerator());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    }

    public static void CloneAndPlace(Vector3 newPosition, GameObject originalGameobject)
    {
        // Clone
        GameObject clone = (GameObject)Instantiate(originalGameobject, newPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        // Place
        clone.transform.position = newPosition;
        // Rename
        clone.name = "Cube@" + clone.transform.position;
    }

    /* from docs.unity.com
    * The execution of a coroutine can be paused at any point using the  yield statement. 
    * The yield return value specifies when the coroutine is resumed. 
    * Coroutines are excellent when modelling behaviour over several frames. 
    * Coroutines have virtually no performance overhead. 
    * StartCoroutine function always returns immediately, however you can yield the result. 
    * This will wait until the coroutine has finished execution.
    */
    IEnumerator SimpleGenerator()
    {
        // In this Coroutine we will instantiate 50 voxels per frame
        uint numberOfInstances = 0;
        uint instancesPerFrame = 50;

        for (int x = 1; x <= SizeX; x++)
        {
            for (int z = 1; <= SizeZ; z++)
            {
                // Compute a random height
                float height = Random.Range(0, SizeY);
                for (int y = 0; y <= height; y++)
                {
                    // Compute the position for every voxel
                    Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(x, y, z);
                    // Call the method giving the new position and a Voxel instance as parameters
                    CloneAndPlace(newPosition, Voxel);
                    // Increment numberOfInstances
                    numberOfInstances++;

                    // If the number of instances per frame was met
                    if (numberOfInstances == instancesPerFrame)
                    {
                        // Reset numberOfInstances
                        numberOfInstances = 0;
                        // Wait for next frame
                        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
                    }
                }//end for
            }//end for
        }//end for
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `the 51 code` mean?

Comment: `for (int z = 1; <= SizeZ; z++)` => you forgot to add `z` there

Comment: i want to say line 51

Comment: i dont see wath u want to say for : (int z = 1; <= SizeZ; z++) => you forgot to add z there ?

Comment: `for (int z = 1; z<= SizeZ; z++)`

Answer (score 4):

In your code, the line

```
for (int z = 1; <= SizeZ; z++)
```

Should be

```
for (int z = 1; z <= SizeZ; z++)
```